# In Symfony/Panther when scraping, waitfor function will throw exception if it timesout - i need it to continue if item is not found

Tags: php, symfony, web-scraping, web-crawler, symfony-panther

I have a database of clinics, and an url to each clinic. All clinic pages are the same in terms of html/css, with different content to scrape.

However, some clinics have no content on their page, and this causes trouble for me.

I have:

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $clinic->url);
$this->client->waitFor('.facility');
```

If `.facility` is not present, the `waitFor()` will `throw exception` because of `timeout`. I need to be able to continue in that case, and not throw an exception. So if it times out, it should continue and not end.

I cannot count the facility items and check it that way, since these are loaded with ajax and are not present at the start of page load.

What I have tried and researched:

[Is it possible for symfony/panther to wait for some elements n times?](https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/450)

[HowTo Wait - PHPWebDriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/wiki/HowTo-Wait)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just catch the exception, like this...

```
try
{
    $this->client->waitFor('.facility');
}
catch (TimeoutException $e)
{
    // Log something here that it was skipped by a timeout...
    // PHP will continue    
}
```

At the top of your class you may need to add (That's what the [code looks like it is using](https://github.com/symfony/panther/blob/main/src/Client.php).):

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeoutException;
```

Also note that the function has other parameters that could be useful:

```
/**
 * @param string $locator The path to an element to be waited for. Can be a CSS selector or Xpath expression.
 *
 * @throws NoSuchElementException
 * @throws TimeoutException
 */
public function waitFor(string $locator, int $timeoutInSecond = 30, int $intervalInMillisecond = 250): PantherCrawler
{
    ....
```

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for. Just to be sure, when you mention "thats what the code looks like it is using" you are refering to https://github.com/symfony/panther/blob/main/src/Client.php#L341 ? But is surely works, so im thankful for your help

Comment: @Patrick, great! Yes at the top of the file they are using that that `TimeoutException` class.